# Tail bounds for sample means of i.i.d random variables where the moment generating function exists

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities, moment-generating-function

I want to figure out the proof of Lemma 4 in the following [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2244583?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents). The lemma states that

> Let $Y_1, Y_2,\ldots Y_m$ be i.i.d random variables such that $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{zY}\right] < \infty$ for $|z|$ sufficiently small. Then there exist $c$ > 0 and $\delta_0 > 0$ such that $\forall \delta < \delta_0$ $$P\left(\left\lvert m^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^{m}Y_i-\mathbb{E}\left[Y\right]\right\rvert\geq\delta\right)=O\left(e^{-cm\delta^2}\right)$$

I can only deduce the generic Chernoff bound but can do no better. I don't know if this bound is the best we can do or if its relaxed for applications.

EDIT: I know, using Markov's inequality, that $$P\left(\left\lvert\overline{Y}_m\right\rvert>\delta\right)\leq \left(M_Y(\delta)\right)^me^{-m\delta^2}$$ where $M_Y(\delta):=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\delta Y}\right]$ is the moment generating function evaluated at $\delta$. However, this is not a *uniform* bound that holds asymptotically. I am sure I am missing something trivial here but it evades me.